# How to initialize a1 , a2 ,..............a100 as symbolss in matlab with code

Tags: matlab

If we want to use a1 as a symbol in Matlab as follows :

syms $a1$, but I want to use all $a1,a2,.....a100$  as syms ,how can do that with simple code in Matlab ,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use
A = sym(zeros(100,1));
to create a matrix of 100 symbolic variables.

In new versions of MATLAB,

A = sym('A', [100 1]); or A = sym('A%d%d', [100 1]); can also be used to create a matrix of symbolic variables.

Comment: ok with your help this is work i think :syms e1;
A = sym(e1*[1:100])

Comment: Yes it work thanks

Comment: no dose not work

Comment: I just checked A = sym(zeros(10,1)) in MATLAB. It is working. Let me know what error it displays.

Comment: they are all zeros?

Comment: Yes, they are all zeros. But you can initialize them to any value. For example, sym([1;2]) creates a matrix of two symbolic variables intialized to 1 and 2. Also, you can modify their values afterwards. For example, A(2) = 4 would set the second element of A to 4.

Comment: ok but this work :a = sym('a', [1 100])

Comment: modifie your answer like this and thanks so much